# "Привет мир" на C#

Tags: php, java, c#, visual-studio, javafx

Мне необходимо объединить в функции текст и переменную. В PHP это выглядело бы так:

```php
$name = "Name";
echo("Hello, " . $name);
```

Мне нужно то же самое, но на C#. Пишу компилятор Java в EXE.

Comment: `$"Текст {переменная}"` или `"текст" + переменная`

Comment: Сейчас попробую.

Comment: А если нужно занести в константу? `const string commands = @"jdk/bin/javac " + MainFile;`

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, `const` являются неизменяемыми. Их значение всегда равно тому, что вы указали при создание.

Answer (score 8):

1. `string.Format("hello {0}", name);`
2. `"Hello" + name;`
3. `$"Hello {name}";`